# How to do subdomain addressing on app engine with custom domain?

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I do something like api.[my website].com on app engine? I have a module called api.yaml with the following components:

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: api.application
  secure: always
```

But when I try api.[my website].com in my browser, it works, but it loads the main page of my website. I have a .* handler for www.[my website].com, which just goes to my homepage... however I would like a separate page for api.[my website].com. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution might be allowing api.[my website].com to point to [my website].com/api/